# Error con ABM en C

Tags: c

estoy realizando el tipico caso de ABM en c, segun estamos viendo en la facultad, inicializamos todos los alumnos en 1 para decir que esta vacio, luego, hago dos funciones mas complementarias, (buscarLibre y buscarAlumno), lo que me sucede a la hora de hacer el alta, es que no me controla, es decir, yo quiero ingresar como maximo 2 legajos y que verifique si el legajo se encuentra cargado o si el sistema esta completo y no esta funcionando y no logro encontrar el error.
El alta me deja hacerla, lo que esta fallando es el control

Dejo las 4 funciones, si alguien podria ayudarme se lo agradeceria un monton

```
 void inicializarAlumnos(eAlumno vec[],int tam)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        vec[i].isEmpty=1;
    }
}
int buscarLibre (eAlumno vec[],int tam)
{
    int indice=-1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        if(vec[i].isEmpty==1)
        {
            indice=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return indice;
}
int buscarAlumno (int legajo, eAlumno vec[], int tam)
{
    int indice= -1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        if(vec[i].legajo == legajo && vec[i].isEmpty == 0)
        {
            indice=i;
            break;
        }

    }
return indice;
}
int altaAlumno (eAlumno vec[], int tam)
{
    int retorno= -1;
    int esta;
    int libre;
    int legajoAux;
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    int n1;
    int n2;
    libre = buscarLibre(vec,tam);
    if(libre == -1)
    {
        printf("\n No hay mas espacio en memoria! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ingrese el legajo: \n");
        scanf("%d", &legajoAux);
        esta=buscarAlumno(legajoAux,vec,tam);
        if(esta != -1)
        {
            printf("El legajo ya se encuentra cargado\n");
            //deberia haber una funcion para mostrar UN alumno
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Ingrese nombre: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nombre);

            printf("Ingrese edad: ");
            scanf("%d", &edad);

            printf("Ingrese sexo: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &sexo);

            printf("Ingrese nota 1: ");
            scanf("%d", &n1);

            printf("Ingrese nota 2: ");
            scanf("%d", &n2);

            //printf("Ingrese fecha ingreso: ");
            //scanf("%d/%d/%d", &fecha.dia, &fecha.mes, &fecha.anio);

            retorno=1;
            printf("Alta exitosa!!!\n\n");
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? Qué es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: Me deja ingresar la cantidad de altas que quiero aunque le ponga un define para que el máximo permitido de altas sea 2, y también me deja cargar legajos repetidos

Comment: Todo eso que cuentas a mi pregunta de Cual es el problema no está en el código que has subido. No hay defines, no se ve cómo llamas a la función de alta y en la función de alta pides los datos al usuario y luego no los guardas en el vector. Piensa que los que te podríamos ayudar no tenemos ni idea de lo que pretendes. Empezar por "el típico caso de ABM". Típico para quién? Para mí desde luego no. Así que si quiero responder me toca tratar de entender tu código directamente. Mala política si quieres una solución rápida...